# java.util.NoSuchElementException while using StringTokenizer in java

Tags: java, arraylist, stringtokenizer

I am recently doing simple project on file reading, writing and comparing string in core java. I have used StringTokenizer for parsing each elements in line. but while doing so, i encounter following error message. 
Any help regarding this, thanks in advance.
Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextElement(Unknown Source)
at com.dhiraj.demo.ComparatorClass.main(ComparatorClass.java:64)
```

My code is like following;

```
String listtable = "listtable.dat";
    ArrayList<ListTableClass> ltc = new ArrayList<ListTableClass>();

    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(listtable);
            BufferedReader bio = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis))){
        String line;
        while((line = bio.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
            StringTokenizer to = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
            //while(tokens.hasMoreElements()){
                //System.out.println(tokens.nextElement());

                //Integer id = Integer.parseInt(to.nextElement().toString().trim());
            //  System.out.println(id);
                Integer id = Integer.parseInt(to.nextElement().toString());

                //int id = Integer.parseInt(to.nextElement().toString().trim());
                System.out.println("i am error");
                String fname = to.nextElement().toString().trim();
                String lname = to.nextElement().toString().trim();
                String address = to.nextElement().toString().trim();
                Integer age = Integer.parseInt(to.nextElement().toString().trim());


                ltc.add(new ListTableClass(id, fname, lname, address, age));

            //}
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);

    }       
    for(ListTableClass t: ltc){
        System.out.println(t.getId());
        System.out.println(t.getFname());
        System.out.println(t.getLname());   
        System.out.println(t.getAddress());     
        System.out.println(t.getAge());         

    }
```

and file sample is:

```
11120|bijaya|khanal|biratnagar|25
11121|chandramani|sapkota|hetauda|25
11117|Hari|Sapkota|bhaktapur|25
11118|pramod|chaulagain|banepa|25
11119|bigyan|shrestha|birjung|25
11120|bijaya|khanal|biratnagar|25
11114|suman|hamal|shangrila|25
11115|kishor|Neupane|Sanepa|25
```

Comment: Are you saying that your sample code above reproduces the error?  Because I just basically copy pasted your code and ran it fine. No errors.  Please make sure that you give us the code that reproduces the error.  Also, it is recommended to use `String.split()` in favor of `StringTokenizer`.   Much easier to use.

Comment: Yes, it is generating error in my IDE. It may be because i have done the same process for other file also.

Comment: so does the error happen with the sample data you provided?  Or does it only happen with different data?  Because, again, I can't get your error with the information you provided.

Comment: The only way it throws this exception is when you do too many nextElement().  What output do you get and what is line 64?  Also, you should be able to do nextToken() because you're turning them back into strings anyway.

Comment: Do you have blank lines at the bottom of your file?  The sample input you provided works just fine for me, but if I add a couple blank lines at the bottom I get a `NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by adding a `toString` to `ListTableClass`, something like

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Id: %d%n" + //
            "Name (lname, fname): %s, %s%n" + //
            "Address: %s%n" + //
            "Age: %d",//
            id, lname, fname, address, age//
            );
}
```

Then I would prefer [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and to read the file from the user's home folder, and finally to program to the `List` interface (and use the diamond operator `<>`) with the `toString` and you should probably check for emtpy lines like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String listtable = "listtable.dat";
    List<ListTableClass> ltc = new ArrayList<>();
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), listtable);
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(f)) {
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] to = line.split("|");
            Integer id = Integer.parseInt(to[0].trim());
            String fname = to[1].trim();
            String lname = to[2].trim();
            String address = to[3].trim();
            Integer age = Integer.parseInt(to[4].trim());
            ltc.add(new ListTableClass(id, fname, lname, address, age));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (ListTableClass t : ltc) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```